# Plot several FITS files in one graph

Tags: python, fits

At the moment, I get three separate graphs.  Ideally I would like to overlay all graphs, so that I only have one plot with multiple FIT files.

I have a folder on my desktop with the HARPS-N data, the extension is

~/Desktop/harpn_sun_release_package_ccf_2018/2018-01-18/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:25:36.145_CCF_A.fits

This is my code so far.. with just three of the fits

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
%matplotlib widget

file_path = [
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:25:36.145_CCF_A.fits',
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:20:10.645_CCF_A.fits',
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:31:00.875_CCF_A.fits']

def plot_fits_file(file_path):
    hdul = fits.open(file_path)
    data = hdul[1].data
    h1 = hdul[1].header
    flux = data[1]
    w = WCS(h1, naxis=1, relax=False, fix=False)
    lam = w.wcs_pix2world(np.arange(len(flux)), 0)[0]
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    plt.plot(lam, flux)
    plt.ylim(0, )
    plt.xlabel('RV')
    plt.ylabel('Normalized CCF')
    plt.title(file_path)
    plt.show()

    
for file_path in spec_list:
    plot_fits_file(file_path)
```

Comment: Your title is word salad. Please review your question and write it as though the reader knows nothing about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: This looks more like a coding issue and may be more appropriate on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm examining CCF's v radial velocity on the HARPS-N site.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `plt.figure()` call outside the function all the lines should appear on the same plot. Also, you can move the `xlabel` and `ylabel` calls outside the function as well since you only need to label the axes once. Finally, overwriting the title of the plot for every file didn't make any sense to me, so I moved that part to the legend.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
%matplotlib widget

file_path = [
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:25:36.145_CCF_A.fits',
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:20:10.645_CCF_A.fits',
    '~/Desktop/r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:31:00.875_CCF_A.fits']

def plot_fits_file(file_path):
    hdul = fits.open(file_path)
    data = hdul[1].data
    h1 = hdul[1].header
    flux = data[1]
    w = WCS(h1, naxis=1, relax=False, fix=False)
    lam = w.wcs_pix2world(np.arange(len(flux)), 0)[0]
    
    plt.plot(lam, flux, label=file_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.ylim(0, )
plt.xlabel('RV')
plt.ylabel('Normalized CCF')

for file_path in spec_list:
    plot_fits_file(file_path)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```